# Why is ping to Google servers and Google DNS so low?

Tags: dns

I noticed that ping to Google DNS and to google.com from Serbia is about 15ms, but google servers are located in California!
http://www.geoiptool.com/en/?IP=173.194.39.110
My dedicated server is located in Germany and our countries are close, but ping is 43ms.
What is the secret?
Can I reduce ping to my server somehow?

Comment: this isnt an appropriate question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has an estimated 900,000+ servers all around the world. Not just in California.
Source: http://www.pandia.com/sew/481-gartner.html

This question is better left to https://serverfault.com/ I believe.
You can see a full list of sites through stackexchange here: https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: You are not right...
Ip address is located in California which I am pinging...
And i checked it from my computer...

Comment: @Luka All Google ip addresses are from California. Even when they actually point to some where in Europe or Asia.

Comment: thx you on answering